Вырезать border, clip-path

нужно вырезать вот такой угол,  в обычном блоке. В вырезанном участке должен быть другой блок, т.е условно мне нужно создать border вокруг блока, который будет буквально прозрачным и вырезатьвсе

Возможно решение из этого вопроса вам поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1579800/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-css-c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8

именно с таким скруглением? или можно без скругления?

@darinkapoznyak думаю у человека проблема именно со скруглением, с прямыми углами с clip-path легко то сделать)

Запросто, не вырезайте ничего, Просто зелёную картинку png возьмите и натяните на блок))
