Правильная стилизация неправильной фигуры со скруглениями на CSS
Все чаще в дизайнах сайтов встречается использование вычурных прямоугольников. Не знаю как описать это словами, поэтому прикладываю примеры:


Речь про желтый и синий прямоугольники со скругленными "выемками" в углах..
Каким способом было бы правильно реализовать такое в CSS?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1579800/264178 // https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1588469/264178
